# Run python server and Kotlin from the same physical dedicated server?

Tags: python, android, kotlin, server, network-programming

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin for client side and server side code.
I also want to run python as a server along side the Kotlin server on the same dedicated hosting hardware.
Basically the Kotlin server will be the client for my Python server.
Python server only communicates within the dedicated hardware and not to the Android app.
The reason I am doing this is because Python server is slow and I want my fast Kotlin server to keep the multiple Android clients running smooth.
If some Android client causes a trigger of the python code then he should only be delayed, all other Android clients should not be affected as they are working on the Kotlin code only.
How will the kotlin client connect to the python server and exchange data to and fro?

Comment: "How will the kotlin client connect to the python server and exchange data to and fro?" -- um, the same way anything else would connect to the Python server. For example, if the Python server offers up HTTP communications on `localhost:8080`, the Kotlin client would use an HTTP client to talk to the Python server on `localhost:8080`.